# Creating a WARC file using a Twitter archive

Tags: cmd.exe, website, archiving, twitter

I've downloaded a Twitter archive that has the following structure:

```
twitter_archive
| assets
+-- fonts (.eot files)
+-- images (icons)
+-- js
| data
+-- various tweet folders containing images
+-- more javascript files
| index.html (launching this brings you to a local webpage in which you 
              can navigate the archive with a Twitter style GUI)
```

I've attempted to use the [warcit](https://github.com/webrecorder/warcit) Python package to use the archive and create a WARC file that can be rendered in https://replayweb.page/.

I was successful in creating the WARC file, but when loaded into replayweb.page it states that "No Pages are defined in this archive. However, when manually navigating to index.html it loads the Twitter Archive GUI as normal.

My question is, what arguments can I use with warcit to define index.html as a page?

The command I've used is:

```
warcit --name twitter_archive -o --no-gzip -d 20221122010159 --index-files=index.html http://website.com/ "E:/twitter_archive/"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the warcit tool to create a WARC file from a local Twitter archive. The warcit tool allows you to create a WARC file from a website by crawling it and saving the pages and associated resources (such as images and stylesheets) to the WARC file.

To create a WARC file that includes the index.html file in your Twitter archive as a page, you can use the --index-files option with the path to the index.html file. For example:

```
warcit --name twitter_archive -o --no-gzip -d 20221122010159 --index-files=E:/twitter_archive/index.html http://website.com/ "E:/twitter_archive/"
```

This will create a WARC file that includes the index.html file as a page, along with any other pages and resources that are linked from it.

If you want to include all of the files in your Twitter archive in the WARC file, you can use the --mirror option instead of the --index-files option. This will create a WARC file that includes all of the files in your Twitter archive, rather than just the ones linked from a specific index file.

```
warcit --name twitter_archive -o --no-gzip -d 20221122010159 --mirror http://website.com/ "E:/twitter_archive/"
```